# Java 1.8: Measure elapsed time in a thread-safe way

Tags: java, thread-safety

I need a simple, high-performance, thread-safe, low accuracy timer / technique (only up to hundreds of ms) to measure elapsed time in my thread-safe function.

How to achieve it in Java?

I took a look at [System.currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) and [System.nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) but none mention any thread-safety guarantees

Comment: I no longer have a Java 1.8 API reference, but maybe `System.currentTimeMillis()` dates back that far?  Alternatively, the nullary constructor for `java.util.Date` has always given you a `Date` representing the current time, and you can use its `getTime()` method to get that in milliseconds since the epoch.  Either approach should support a simple timer.

Comment: Is `currentTimeMillis` thread-safe? I can't find any documentation that explicitly mention it

Comment: It has to be - because calls to `currentTimeMillis()` can occur anytime from any code (JRE and user code). There would be no way to reliably synchronize calls from different sources.

Comment: Do you have any supporting documentation that specifically talk about thread-safetyness? Can't seem to find it in the API docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: There is no documentation about thread-safetyness because it's not necessary. The method get a long value from the underlying operating system and returns it. where do you think are the problems of thread-safety?

Comment: Fair enough. Can you make this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no documentation about thread-safetyness because it's not necessary.

The methods get a long value from the underlying operating system and return it.

Where do you think are the problems of thread-safety?